# PHP - Mysql response handling

Tags: php

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Get the category data depending on the language and also get the administrators for the current category. The output is a result of joining three tables.

**Problem:**

There could be several different ''user_id'' values but the rest of the table will be with the same data.

**Question**

Is there a way to get the result of the query in a single row or somehow normalize the output so there are no duplications? I've tried with "array_unique()", but it does not give me the desired output.

The image represents the result I get, but this would give me doubled/tripled data in the columns( status, image, language, translation ) as there could be more than one user_id administrating the current category, but the rest of the data will be the same.
[image: result from procedure]

The stored procedure looks like:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE ct int;
select count(id) INTO ct from category where id= c_id;
IF ct > 0 THEN
select 
c.status,
c.image,
ca.user_id,
cl.language,
cl.translation
from
    `category` c
        inner join
    category_translate cl
        on c.id = cl.category_id
        inner join 
    category_admin ca
        on c.id = ca.category_id
        where c.id=c_id;
end if; 

END
```

Thx!

Comment: What is the context of that image? Is it the result that you want? The result that you're getting? One of your tables? If the latter, where are the rest (you mention three)? You're not really giving us much to go on here.

Comment: Have you looked into `GROUP BY`?

Comment: {GROUP BY } would return either only one row with user_id = 2 if I group it by id, or the same result if grouped by user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided the best option here is to modify the current procedure and exclude the user_id, and create separate procedure to give me the administrators.